# Delete or Keep observations by factor from another variable funtion

Tags: r

I would like to only keep observations by ID that have 3 or more INSTANCES. Or, the other way, delete observations by ID that have less than 3 INSTANCES. SAMPLE DATA:

```
Instances <- data.frame(ID=c(111111, 111111, 111111, 111111, 
222222, 222222,
333333, 333333, 333333), 
INSTANCE=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3), 
AMOUNT=c(100,120,108,112, 60, 65, 85, 90, 101))

Instances$ID <- as.factor(Instances$ID)
Instances$INSTANCE <- as.factor(Instances$INSTANCE)
```

From this sample I would expect a return of all the observations from ID 111111 and 333333 but none from 222222.

I'm sure there is need for the piping function in magrittr that I can create by ID. 
When I attempt this I fail at keeping the function of INSTANCE > 3 tied to ID. I'm still understanding %>% and reading still about it, but in the meantime any help and potential explanation as to why/how that works would be appreciated. Stay Warm out there people.

Comment: How about `Instances[ave(rep(1, nrow(Instances)), Instances$ID, FUN = length) >= 3,]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base solution

```
a_x <- ave(Instances$INSTANCE,
           Instances$ID,
           FUN = max)

Instances[a_x >= 3,]

      ID INSTANCE AMOUNT
1 111111        1    100
2 111111        2    120
3 111111        3    108
4 111111        4    112
7 333333        1     85
8 333333        2     90
9 333333        3    101
```

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr) 

Instances %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(max_instance = max(INSTANCE)) %>%
  filter(max_instance >= 3) %>%
  select(-max_instance)

      ID INSTANCE AMOUNT
1 111111        1    100
2 111111        2    120
3 111111        3    108
4 111111        4    112
7 333333        1     85
8 333333        2     90
9 333333        3    101
```

#### Data (note I did not convert `ID` or `INSTANCE` to factors)

```
Instances <- data.frame(ID=c(111111, 111111, 111111, 111111, 
222222, 222222,
333333, 333333, 333333), 
INSTANCE=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3), 
AMOUNT=c(100,120,108,112, 60, 65, 85, 90, 101))
```

Comment: What's funny is I had already created a Max Instance variable that I had forgetten about, dat$MaxPayInstance <- ave(dat$Instance, dat$LID, FUN=max)

Comment: Why would the dplyr version of this turn this function into "A Tibble"? dat%>% count(Termed)

Answer (score 2):

As posted in my earlier comment, this should work regardless of your data structure for `Instances$INSTANCE`. I use `ave` and just create a vector of 1's to summarize:

```
Instances[ave(rep(1, nrow(Instances)), Instances$ID, FUN = length) >= 3,]

#      ID INSTANCE AMOUNT
#1 111111        1    100
#2 111111        2    120
#3 111111        3    108
#4 111111        4    112
#7 333333        1     85
#8 333333        2     90
#9 333333        3    101
```

Answer (score 1):

This makes a count of each ID using the dplyr::n() function, names it 'size' and returns those where size > 2:

```
library(dplyr)
Instances  %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(size=n()) %>% filter(size>2)

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
      ID INSTANCE AMOUNT  size
  <fctr>   <fctr>  <dbl> <int>
1 111111        1    100     4
2 111111        2    120     4
3 111111        3    108     4
4 111111        4    112     4
5 333333        1     85     3
6 333333        2     90     3
7 333333        3    101     3
```

If I had been using `ave`, I would have tried: `ave(Instances$ID, Instances$ID, FUN=length)`